# University of Washington rgb-d slam package availability

Tags: navigation, mapping, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I came across some fantastic work put out by the University of Washington doing room mapping and localization with just a laptop and a kinect and wanted to know if the software is available.
The link to the demo videos and website are here, but they do not seem to point to the software.

http://www.cs.washington.edu/ai/Mobile_Robotics/projects/interactive-mapping/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31032/university-of-washington-rgb-d-slam-package-availability/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked them before and they said it wasn't in any shape to be released.

---

Originally posted by [amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2073/amigo/) with karma: 93 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2012-04-02**:
thanks for the reply. The only equivalent I see to it currently is at http://www.ros.org/news/2011/03/3d-visual-slam-with-mobile-robots.html